# AND and OR operator not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I am trying to use AND and OR operator, to compare values without using if else statements.

```
#!/bin/sh
A=5                                             
B=8 
[ $A -gt $B ] && echo "A is greater than B" || [ $A -lt $B ] && echo "A is lesser than B" || [ $A -eq $B ] && echo "A is equal to B"
```

It should print "A is lesser than B", but I am getting following output.

```
A is lessar than B
A is equal to B
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You might want to group them in curly brackets. Especially everything after the first `||`. There are rules of precedence that apply here. Or in short: the script does what you tell it to, not what you want it to (unless you tell it what you want) ;)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, after using brackets, I am able to get the desired output.

Comment: just as a remark. What you did (using subshells) is perfectly fine, too. But it carries different connotations. For example something set inside the subshell or a `cd` executed in it, will not carry outside. So this may be fine for your example code, but can become unwieldy in real world situations. I strongly recommend curly brackets like so `{ command1; command2; [[ condition1 ]] && command3; }` (note the semi-colons, the last semi-colon would not be necessary when using subshells with `( command ... )`).

Comment: 1) I rollbacked your answer posted as an edit into the question 2) I voted your question up 3) I voted to leave it closed. Further remarks: 4) unexplained code snippet is VLQ (as answer) 5) closure of your question as dupe is not so bad, it only means that it was already answered, i.e. it is essentially the same as the original. 6) If you believe your question is essentially different as the other, then write a convincing argument for it. In theory it should be a comment, but if you edit it into the question, in order to make it better visible for the reviewers, that is yet so or so tolerable.